# Show another button where the original button was located

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Currently in my form starting with  `@using (Html.BeginForm`
I have a submit button like this:

```
<input id="submitButton" type="submit" value="Update stuff" />
```

Now after they submit, I want to show ANOTHER button instead of that button for example:

```
<input id="continueButton" type="button" value="Continie to next page" />
```

So I understand I should have a property on my model for example `@Model.ShowSubmitButton`  that goes true or false.  From my learning I should do something close to

```
@if(Model.ShowSubmitButton)
    <input id="submitButton" type="submit" value="Update stuff" />
else
    <input id="continueButton" type="button" value="Continie to next page" />
```

But I can't get the Razor syntax wrong if actually my way of doing it is correct to begin it. So I need help with this part.  And I want do it with MVC, not with JS because I don't know JS yet.

Comment: Without JS you can do this. Submit the form and from your controller return the same view but by setting the `ShowSubmitButton` property to false. This way the same view is loaded and now with continue button

Comment: ^^^^ Here is the solution for your problem. But i suggest. start learning js. It is so much fun.

Comment: I know I should set that boolean property of mine to FALSE in the controller after a successful submit, my question is how should I change my RAZOR code to utilize it?

Comment: @Bohn your existing code already handles it.. Your doing it right. With the If else

Comment: If you say your syntax is wrong.. Then may be it's because of the braces {}. Add the braces for your if and else..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use it like this

```
 @if(Model.ShowSubmitButton)
 {
    <input id="submitButton" type="submit" value="Update stuff" />
 }
 else
 {
    <input id="continueButton" type="button" value="Continie to next page" />
 }
```

> Last but not least get your hands dirty with JS

Comment: I know I should set that boolean property of mine to FALSE in the controller after a successful submit, my question is how should I change my RAZOR code to utilize it?

Comment: yuo have already show it in your code like this @if(Model.ShowSubmitButton)
    <input id="submitButton" type="submit" value="Update stuff" />
else
    <input id="continueButton" type="button" value="Continie to next page" />

Comment: What I have is WRONG when I type it in VisualStudio. The SYNTAX is WRONG

Comment: yeah those { } around it fixed it I guess. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your initial attempt, and what rashfmnb's answer solved for you was because of the `{}` as you deduced. Since you said "it fixed it I guess", I'll explain why:

Razor parses your markup as HTML, except where it knows that it should be reading it as C# code. You typically do that by starting a statement with the `@` symbol. You did that when you started your if. But then, you have an HTML element, the `<input>`. Once that closes, Razor doesn't know that it's supposed to go back to parse the `else` as C#. It's going to assume it's just plain text that should be a part of the DOM.

By adding the curly braces around the conditional statements, you're telling the Razor parser that when it gets to the closing brace, it should go back to parsing it as C# code. That is why the `else` is now picked up again and only one or the other is displayed.

Comment: Thanks for explanation.